# Obtain String from a Cell and refer to another Sheet using it

Tags: string, excel

Let us say I am using sheet2 in excel and I wish to obtain data from another sheet, say sheet1.
So for now I am writing in Sheet2 the following

```
='Sheet1'!A1
```

However the string `Sheet1` is written in a particular cell in `Sheet2`, say `A2`.

I would like to know whether it is possible to write something like the following:

```
='A2'!A1
```

which would have the same function as:

```
='Sheet1'!A1
```

i.e. obtain the string `sheet1` from a cell in `sheet2` and use it to refer to a cell in `sheet1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the `INDIRECT` function:

```
=INDIRECT(A2&"!A1")
```